# Zend framework 1.12 pass optional parameter in Routing

Tags: zend-framework

My Routing is this.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'car-insurance/*',
            array(
                'controller' => 'car',
                'action'     => 'moreinfo',
                'module' => 'insurance',
               ) 
               );

         $router->addRoute('car-insurance', $route);
```

This is working fine if user hit **domain_name/car-insurance**

But I want to redirect user to the single page if he hit on
**domain_name/car-insurance/slug**

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'car-insurance/:slug/*',
            array(
                'controller' => 'car',
                'action'     => 'moreinfo',
                'module' => 'insurance',
                'slug' =>''

            ) 
        );

         $router->addRoute('car-insurance', $route);
```

Because **$router->addRoute('car-insurance', $route);** can initialize one time only.

Comment: i could not understand your question. please edit it to find your answer..

Comment: Actually I wanted  to set the route with slug and without slug. Now my problem has been solved. I had to change the priority of route only.
Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Hi @Deepaksaini Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post your solution as an answer to help future visitors please :)